# How to configure datasource for remote database connection in spring boot application

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, configuration, remote-access

I am developing a application in spring boot. I am using Mysql database for persistance. I have my database in remote server. How to configure datasource for remote database connection?

Please help me configuring this in both property file as well as datasource bean configuration using annotations in my config class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `application.properties` file, add:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://<dbhost>:<dbport>/<db>
spring.datasource.username=<username>
spring.datasource.password=<password>
```

Your Maven `.pom` should have:

```
<!-- JPA Data (We are going to use Repositories, Entities, Hibernate, etc...) -->

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>

<!-- Use MySQL Connector-J -->

<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Or the corresponding `compile` entries in your `build.gradle` file if you're using gradle.
When these are on your classpath, you can start implementing repositories, e.g.

```
public interface YourRepository extends CrudRepository<YourModel, Long> {

}
```

for a quick start and more details, have a look a the [official starter project](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/).

Comment: I am getting exception like this `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.`

Comment: That sounds like your MySql Server is not reachable at all. Are you sure it's listening for TCP/IP connections? As far as I know its configured to only listen to connections from the localhost. Do you have access to the my.cnf config file?

Comment: It was listening only from localhost. Changed it. Working now thank you.

Comment: Won't you also have to grant remote access to the user? `GRANT ALL ON *.* TO <user>@'<ipAddress>' IDENTIFIED BY '<password>'`

Answer (score 1):

You have to put following config in your `application.yml`

```
spring:
    datasource:
        url: jdbc:mysql://<IP>:<PORT>/<DB>
        username: <username>
        password: <pwd>
        driver-class-name: <db_driver> (e.g. com.mysql.jdbc.Driver)

    jpa:
        database-platform: <db_dialect> (e.g org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect)
```

Spring boot will see this config and autoconfigure data sources provided you have `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` in your class path.